# Apostrophe treated as end of string in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, apostrophe

I have a xml where i need to check for a condition

```
[preceding-sibling::heading/title='ABC's Notes. --']
```

This expression is throwing error as  "expected  "]" found s ". I need to search for title "ABC's Notes. --" but i think 'ABC' is being interpreted as a separate string.

How should i write the above code to make apostrophe not being treated as end of string. Any inputs would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Both double (`"…"`) and single (`'…'`) quotes can be used to delimit strings in XSLT. To include either in a string either use the other quotes for the string (in your case switching to double quotes would work, or use the XML entities: `&apos;` or `&quot;` for single and double quotes respectively.